# haskell, case of like fmap

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a function of type `foo :: a -> a -> Either String TypeConstructor`
`foo` can return both `throwError String` and something of `TypeConstructor`.

I would like to do something like `fmap`.  I mean that I would like to `case (foo x y z) of ...` where `...` means different values (it depends on used constructor value in foo).

Is there exista any way to do it ?

Comment: there is a `Functor` instance for `Either` already - so if you provide one for `TypeConstructor` (which is a strange name here) - you can just to `fmap . fmap`

Answer (score 2):

A basic way could be to pattern match everything

```
case foo x y of
  Left string -> ...
  Right (Cons1 z w) -> ...
  Right (Cons2 a b c) -> ...
  Right Cons3 -> ...
```

where `Cons1, ...` are the value constructors of `TypeConstructor`.

Comment: Yes, but then my error is not 'underground'  - it is why I would like to use something like `fmap`

Comment: @HaskellFun Then I'm afraid I can not fully understand the question. Maybe you can use the `either` combinator to remove the left/right pattern matching, but it seems you still need to use `case` for all the constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly write

```
case (foo x y) of ...
```

and then pattern match on the type constructors of `TypeConstructor` since `foo x y` does not have the correct type (it is `Either String TypeConstructor`).

However, you can define a function which pattern matches on the type constructors of `TypeConstructor` and then `fmap` this over the result of `foo x y` as shown below.

```
import Control.Monad.Except (throwError)

data Type = Int Int
          | Str String
          deriving (Show)

foo :: Int -> String -> Either String Type
foo n s =
    if n == 0
        then throwError "Zero"
        else return (Str s)

bar x y = fmap f (foo x y)
    where
        f a = case a of
            Int n -> Int (n +  x)
            Str s -> Str (s ++ y)
```